# Can we add python libraries directly on ev3dev such as numPy etc?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lego-mindstorms

I am wondering if it's possible to add other libraries other than ev3dev Python on EV3 dev? If possible, how to do it?

Comment: It should be possible via ssh and pip. But I ain't sure.

Comment: you're right, after spending my whole day thanks for your clue. I used ssh and install pip, then using pip I install the library. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes!, I tried to find a way to download pip to ev3dev and i found one. just type in the terminal:

```
sudo easy_install3 pythonLibraryName
```